# Как получить доступ к системной директории при помощи fstream c++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, fstream

Я могу изменить что-то в определенной системной директории при помощи `sudo`, по почему-то если я вызываю свою программу при помощи `sudo` она уже не может получить доступ, что я могу сделать?

`fstream` open используется вот так:

```
ifstream led_r, led_g, led_b;
string led_data;

led_r.open("/sys/class/leds/0003:054C:09CC.0003:red/bigthness");
cout << errno << endl;
led_g.open("/sys/class/leds/0003:054C:09CC.0003:blue/bigthness");
led_b.open("/sys/class/leds/0003:054C:09CC.0003:green/bigthness");

if (!led_r || !led_g || !led_b) {
    cout << "can not get leds" << endl;
} else {
    led_r >> led_data;
    cout << led_data << endl; 
}
```

осуществляя проверку на открытие файла, получаю отрицательный результат

Comment: какую ошибку? что в `errno`?

Comment: Видимо в `/etc/sudoers` у вас нет вот такой строчки `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Comment: @fat-zer да, написал не верно, выполняю проверку на открытие файла с помощью if(!led_r) и тут обнаруживаю что у меня он не открыт, сейчас исправлю в вопросе

Comment: @avp это для того чтобы все программы запускались от sudo?

Comment: @avp такая строчка есть

Comment: @THND, именно так. Если есть, то какая-то ошибка в программе. Отлаживайте

Comment: @THND, что в `errno`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer в errno 0, ошибки нет и c++ не ругается, поэтому я считаю что неисправность связана с sudo ......

upd: кажется я не правильно проверил, теперь выводит 2

Comment: @THND, почти наверняка — нет: `sudo` только меняет uid (+делает ещё кое-какую очистку) и запускает указанную программу... на работу самой программы он ни как не влияет... ищи глупую ошибку или приведи [mcve] (ну и `ls -l /sys/class/leds/0003:054C:09CC.0003:red/bigthness`)... в частности `!` в `if`'е у тебя не лишний?

Comment: @Fat-Zer ls -l отображает файл: "-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 дек  6 00:00 /sys/class/leds/0003:054C:09CC.0003:blue/brightness", a при простой замене в коде на собственно этот cpp-файл все выводится отлично

Comment: Обычный [open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) эти файлы открывает? (Если нет, то что печатает perror()?)

Comment: Должно быть не bightness, а brightness

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev какой ужас, вы правы, прошу прощения за такой вопрос

Comment: странно... в `errno` должно было быть `ENOENT`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer 2 и есть ENOENT. Не везде, наверное, но в линуксах вроде во всех.

Comment: мм... `upd` в комменте OP'а не заметил...